# How to manipulate data from a list in Python

Tags: python

I want to be able to manipulate the values of a Python dict (adding them in fact) using the strings in its keys. For example, here's a dict that I have:

```
dict = {'010': 155, '001': 1363, '011': 68, '101': 356, '100': 1377, '111': 36, '110': 69, '000': 4768}
```

Say I want to extract and/or add the values of those **keys that ended with `1`** (like `'001': 1363, '011': 68, '101': 356, '111': 36` in this example), and put them somewhere like in a value `those_that_start_with_1 = 1363 + 68 + 356 + 36` or an array  or something. How do I go about doing that?

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I didn't really have a clue, I'm quite a beginner. But a lot of people seems to have given the answer and it worked! So I'll wait until I can accept an answer and close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
tmp = [ v for k, v in dict.items() if k.endswith('1') ]
```

`[]` syntax is list comprehension syntax (creates list based on expression inside. `v` is value, that will be put into the list. `dict.items()` is an iterator, that produces `v` values and returns all items in `dict` as pairs (first is key, second value), `if` condition filters values put into the `tmp` - only those for which key ends with `1` will be let thru.

If you want to add them you can try:

```
sum((v for k, v in dict.items() if k.endswith('1')), 0)
```

Comment: @Radowslaw Cybulski , yep, missed that, values are also need.

Answer (score 2):

try this, if did not understand the dictionary comprehension -

```
a = 0
for k in dict:
    if k.endswith('1'):
        a += dict[k]

print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the dictionary using `item()` function and do the follow (per your example) -

`sum([v for k, v in dict.items() if k.endswith('1')])`

See more [here](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension) about dictionary comprehension

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```py
dic = {'010': 155, '001': 1363, '011': 68, '101': 356, '100': 1377, '111': 36, '110': 69, '000': 4768}
print(sum([dic[key] for key in dic if key.endswith('1') ]))

# 1823
```

and one thing, [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict) is a [Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-functions) in Python. Please don't use [Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-functions) as your variable names.